# Merging 2 tables in a single table with different schema

Tags: microsoft-sync-framework

I would like to sync a single table with the result of a Join between 2 tables. I designed these dbs for exercitation (the EQUI JOIN is between PERSON.AddressId and ADDRESS.Id):

How can I perform the provisioning of dbs and the synchronization?

Until now I developed some examples about common scenarios, like different table names, different column names or the removing of columns.

How can this be achieved?

**-->FIRST DB<--**

PERSON:

->Id(PK, int, not null)

->Name(nchar(10), not null)

->Surname(nchar(10), not null)

->AddressId(FK, int, not null)

ADDRESS:

->Id(PK, int, not null)

->Street(nchar(10), not null)

->City(nchar(10), not null)

->Country(nchar(10), not null)

---

**-->SECOND DB<--**

CUSTOMER:

->Id(PK, int, not null)

->Name(nchar(10), not null)

->Surname(nchar(10), not null)

->Address(nchar(10), not null)

->City(nchar(10), not null)

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell from the documentation, the Schema's need to match for the Sync to work.  You can sync between tables with the same schema but different names using the GlobalName property of the DbSyncTableDescription.  See JuneT's post:

http://jtabadero.wordpress.com/2011/05/08/synching-tables-with-different-table-names/

For this particular situation, I think you'd be best served by creating Person and Address on Second DB, then creating "Customer" as a view (also on Second DB) to present the two tables in a consolidated manner.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've already read JuneT's post, the different names are not a problem... The problem is how to perform the join...

The solution you suggested is right and clever, but unfortunately I can't adopt it. I can't change the already existing db schema so I can't add Person and Address on Second DB!

Comment: @jfish, you can sync different schemas as well.

Comment: You cannot use views in a sync scope. @JuneT just set me straight in a comment to my answer (which I promptly deleted).

"change tracking is done at table level. which tracking table will the view use? how will the view tell if there was a change?"